# Append some dynamic text to this. in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

How to append or add text dynamically after this.

Here is my function

```
@observable accountName="John";
@observable accountEmailid="John@icicletech.com";
@observable accountPassword="john123456";

@action changeValues(text,fieldName){


 this.{{fieldName}}=text;
}
```

I don't want to write three functions to change values -

```
- this.accountName,
- this.accountEmailid,
- this.accountPassword.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use like this:

```
this[fieldName]=text;
```

It is equivalent to  this.propertyname. So change your code to:

```
@action changeValues(text,fieldName){

 this[fieldName]=text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ved already provided you a correct answer. But I suggest you to take better grasp from **MobX** and consider following:

```
const user = mobx.observable({
  accountName: 'John',
  accountEmailId: 'John@icicletech.com',
  accountPassword: 'john123456',
});
```

This can be provided to the component and accessed directly via props, like `user.accountName` either through the *action* or in the *observer* component.